# Multi-voltage power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

Is there any way to check if a power supply is auto switching multi-voltage input (120-230VAC) with an output of 6VDC? The supply is an electronic power supply (not transformer based) but has absolutely no information on it. I do not want to fry it by trying 230VAC, as it does work on 120VAC. Thanks.

Comment: If there are no markings on the case and you don't know where it came from... probably not.

Comment: open the case and look at the parts inside.  probably easier to just replace it.

Comment: _"The supply is an electronic power supply (not transformer based)..."_ - Switching power supplies like that are also transformer-based. No transformer means no isolation between mains and output.

Comment: @marcelm not that there aren't such horrible, horrible devices... Though they luckily can't legally be imported into the EU nor the US as consumer devices.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this check; one, of course, is to examine the
power supply for a label.  Most AC-input power supplies are well-labeled so that
the user does not need to guess how to safely plug them in.   It may
be necessary to examine the very fine print, closely. It is sometimes
necessary to ensure that a switch or jumper connection is made, on
some older power supplies, to select a voltage range.

The other way, is to reverse-engineer the power supply, by examining the
internal circuitry.   Sometimes the power connector is suitable only for one
national standard power connection, and examining the plug is a very
strong hint.

Checking the output power is easy; just apply a voltmeter while a
suitable load (usually a resistor) is attached.   One would use the
voltmeter, also, before touching any metal on an unlabeled box that
accepts AC power, to ensure you don't get a shock.

Comment: The question does state that the transformer has no markings on it. So why suggest that he checks the labels? RTFQC

Comment: @Gineer Very fine print, pale grey-on-white, molded lettering, are not easy to read.  I've seen a variety of power supplies, but none without some labels, somewhere.